# JQuery, toggle, passing in a variable

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm new to jQuery and have setup a function to toggle a div open/closed. Works great.  But I have 6 places I need it on the page.   So would like to change the id #show as a passed in variable to I can accomplish this for 6 divs using one jQuery function.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.myClass').hide();
$('#show').toggle(function(){
$('.myClass').slideDown("fast"); 
$(this).attr("src","/images/minus.png" );
},function(){
$('.myClass').slideUp("fast"); 
$(this).attr("src", "/images/plus.png" );
});
}); 
</script>

<h2><img id="show" src="/images/plus.png"><span class="toggleText">DivisionI</span>    
</h2>
<div class="myClass">
my code to show....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.myClass').hide();
    $('.show').toggle(function(){
        var showdiv = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.' + showdiv).slideDown("fast"); 
        $(this).attr("src","/images/minus.png" );
    },function(){
        var showdiv = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.' + showdiv).slideUp("fast"); 
        $(this).attr("src", "/images/plus.png" );
    });
}); 
</script>

<h2><img id="show1" class="show" src="/images/plus.png"><span class="toggleText">DivisionI</span>    
</h2>
<div class="show1 myclass">
my code to show....
</div>
<h2><img id="show2" class="show" src="/images/plus.png"><span class="toggleText">DivisionI</span>    
</h2>
<div class="show2 myclass">
my code to show....
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  I have been struggling with this, now I'm so glad I decided to give stack overflow a try.  Still learning jQuery so really appreciated you putting in all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass jQuery objects into functions:

```
var toggleDiv = function($el){
    $el.slideDown();
    //blablabla
};

toggleDiv($('#el'));
```